# Outlook 2016 - show sent messages in conversation list on the left

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

I use the conversation view so I can keep track of threads, but it's confusing not seeing my own replies in the list. Is there a way to get it to show my replies by default?

I can see my replies if I click a thread and then click the <kbd>Conversation</kbd> arrow shaped button. But what I want is to see my replies in the thread list on the left by default.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have the same problem in Outlook 2011 for Mac; I think **this configuration is not possible.**

As shown in the following links from the MS documentation, it looks like the option [exists for the Windows version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-email-messages-by-conversation-0eeec76c-f59b-4834-98e6-05cfdfa9fb07), but it is not available in the [Mac OS X version](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-e-mail-messages-by-conversation-0ec4af07-6fb3-4499-bcab-3d01a090144c). As you alluded to, (your own) sent messages appear in in "reading pane" but do not render in the message list.

**One workaround is to automatically BCC yourself on everything**. Enable this by **Outlook** menu -> **Preferences...** -> **Email** section -> **Composing** -> **Format and account** section -> enable "When sending messages, automatically BCC myself." This will have the effect of putting a copy of messages you send into your Inbox, so they will render in the conversation view/pane. I'm not sure if this will result in duplicate messages rendering in the "reading pane" for conversations. I'm personally not willing to do this, but it should/does work.

Until or unless...

- I'm missing something, or
- I learn some fancy keyboard shortcut or other UI trick, or
- Give up my convictions and BCC myself on everything (which *does* render properly),

this interface (and its inconsistency) is unusable. Back to Apple Mail for me.

Comment: See my answer below.  It works when using Raw Query.

Comment: To have to automatically Bcc: oneself is reminding me of the method I had to use at the beginning of the E-mail, 40 years ago. This is the prehistorical way .

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer!  It involves using the applescript editor to get it to work.

http://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2016/02/received-and-sent-messages-in-single.html

> - Run Outlook
> - Highlight the Mailbox we are going to include, Inbox or Sent. We want to get this mailbox's folder id.
> - Start a Mac Spotlight search
> - Enter ~applesoft~ `AppleScript Editor` and Enter to bring up the applesoft editor.
> - Enter the following in the applescript editor and run it
>
>   ```
>   on run {}
>   tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
>   get selected folder
>   end tell
>   end run
>   ```
>
> It should return the results of the execution mail folder id `109` of
>   application "Microsoft Outlook" Do the same thing for the other
>   mailbox.  My mailbox numbers were `109` (Inbox) and `112` (Sent)
>
> - Click on the Search field in the upper right hand corner of the Outlook view.
> - This will enable the search tab and ribbon
> - Select the Search tab
> - Make sure you are still have a normal mailbox selected (not a Smart Folder)
> - Select "All Mail" in the Ribbon Bar
> - Press the Advanced search button in the ribbon
> - Select Raw Query from the drop list.
> - Enter the following query, replacing `109` and `112` with the mailboxes numbers retrieved above.
>
>   ```
>   com_microsoft_outlook_folderID == 109 || com_microsoft_outlook_folderID == 112
>   ```
> - Press Enter.  The message list should populate with the combined content of the two folders. Conversations in this combined Index/Sent
>     folder will include both inbound and outbound messages.
> - Press Save Search in the Search ribbon bar and enter the name of your new Smart Folder.

Another helpful link was a list of all the Raw Query keys:

https://gist.github.com/EmilVarona/78ae2aff409922686ebff4cea785aed4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.apple.com/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.apple.com/metadata file:///System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Resources/MetadataSchema.xsd">
  <!--  
    Compiled from /Applications/Microsoft\ Outlook.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/Microsoft\ Outlook\ Spotlight\ Importer.mdimporter/Contents/Resources/schema.xml
    with info from http://xensoft.com/search-mac-outlook-2011-mail-with-raw-queries/
  -->
      <types>
        <type name="com.microsoft.outlook15.contact">
            <allattrs>
                kMDItemTitle
                kMDItemPhoneNumbers
                kMDItemEmailAddresses
                kMDItemInstantMessageAddresses
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_recordID
                com_microsoft_outlook_folderID
                com_microsoft_outlook_accountID
                kMDItemCity
                kMDItemStateOrProvince
                kMDItemCountry
                com_microsoft_outlook_flag
                com_microsoft_outlook_nickname
                com_microsoft_outlook_company
                com_microsoft_outlook_department
                com_microsoft_outlook_jobTitle
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeURL
                com_microsoft_outlook_workURL
                com_microsoft_outlook_bloodType
                com_microsoft_outlook_spouse
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld1
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld2
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld3
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld4
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld5
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld6
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld7
                com_microsoft_outlook_customFld8
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeStreet
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeCity
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeState
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeZip
                com_microsoft_outlook_homeCountry
                com_microsoft_outlook_firstName
                com_microsoft_outlook_lastName
                com_microsoft_outlook_suffix
                com_microsoft_outlook_title
                com_microsoft_outlook_notes
                com_microsoft_outlook_workStreet
                com_microsoft_outlook_workCity
                com_microsoft_outlook_workState
                com_microsoft_outlook_workZip
                com_microsoft_outlook_workCountry
                com_microsoft_outlook_otherStreet
                com_microsoft_outlook_otherCity
                com_microsoft_outlook_otherState
                com_microsoft_outlook_otherZip
                com_microsoft_outlook_otherCountry
                com_microsoft_outlook_interests
                com_microsoft_outlook_japanese
                com_microsoft_outlook_birthday
                com_microsoft_outlook_anniversary
                com_microsoft_outlook_customDate1
                com_microsoft_outlook_customDate2
                com_microsoft_outlook_children
                com_microsoft_outlook_furigana_full_name
                com_microsoft_outlook_firstNameFurigana
                com_microsoft_outlook_lastNameFurigana
                com_microsoft_outlook_companyFurigana
                com_microsoft_outlook_spouseFurigana
                com_microsoft_outlook_childrenFurigana
                com_microsoft_outlook_interests
                com_microsoft_outlook_projects
                com_microsoft_outlook_categories
                com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory
                com_microsoft_outlook_flagged
                com_microsoft_outlook_isgroup
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasStartDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_startDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasDueDate
                kMDItemDueDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_reminder
                com_microsoft_outlook_completed
                com_microsoft_outlook_completedDate
            </allattrs>
            <displayattrs>kMDItemTitle
                kMDItemPhoneNumbers
                kMDItemEmailAddresses
                kMDItemInstantMessageAddresses
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
            </displayattrs>
        </type>
        <type name="com.microsoft.outlook15.event">
            <allattrs>com_microsoft_outlook_has_text_content
                kMDItemTextContent
                kMDItemTitle
                com_microsoft_outlook_recordID
                com_microsoft_outlook_folderID
                com_microsoft_outlook_accountID
                kMDItemCoverage
                kMDItemDueDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasStartDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasDueDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_startDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_endDate
                kMDItemWhereFroms
                kMDItemComment
                com_microsoft_outlook_timeZone
                com_microsoft_outlook_recurrence
                com_microsoft_outlook_recurring
                com_microsoft_outlook_allDay
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_reminder
                com_microsoft_outlook_freeBusy
                com_microsoft_outlook_free_busy_value
                com_microsoft_outlook_parentRecordID
                kMDItemContactKeywords
                kMDItemKeywords
                kMDItemProjects
                com_microsoft_outlook_projects
                com_microsoft_outlook_categories
                com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory
                com_microsoft_outlook_attendees
                com_microsoft_outlook_attendee_emails
            </allattrs>
            <displayattrs>kMDItemTitle
                kMDItemCoverage
                kMDItemDueDate
                kMDItemWhereFroms
           </displayattrs>
        </type>
        <type name="com.microsoft.outlook15.message">
            <allattrs>kMDItemTitle
                com_microsoft_outlook_recordID
                kMDItemContentCreationDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_messageSent
                com_microsoft_outlook_messageReceived
                com_microsoft_outlook_priority
                com_microsoft_outlook_flag
                com_microsoft_outlook_unread
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
                kMDItemCoverage
                kMDItemKeywords
                kMDItemProjects
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_text_content
                kMDItemTextContent
                kMDItemAuthors
                kMDItemRecipients
                com_microsoft_outlook_folderID
                com_microsoft_outlook_junkLikelihood
                com_microsoft_outlook_size
                com_microsoft_outlook_newsAccountID
                com_microsoft_outlook_accountID
                com_microsoft_outlook_repliedTo
                com_microsoft_outlook_forwarded
                com_microsoft_outlook_redirected
                com_microsoft_outlook_toRecipients
                com_microsoft_outlook_toEmailAddresses
                com_microsoft_outlook_ccRecipients
                com_microsoft_outlook_ccEmailAddresses
                com_microsoft_outlook_bccRecipients
                com_microsoft_outlook_bccEmailAddresses
                com_microsoft_outlook_attachments
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_attachments
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_mentioned_me
                com_microsoft_outlook_projects
                com_microsoft_outlook_categories
                com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory
                com_microsoft_outlook_flagged
                com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses            
                com_microsoft_outlook_recpient_email_addresses
                com_microsoft_outlook_isFromMailingList
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasStartDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_startDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasDueDate
                kMDItemDueDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_reminder
                com_microsoft_outlook_completed
                com_microsoft_outlook_completedDate
            </allattrs>
            <displayattrs>kMDItemContentCreationDate
                kMDItemAuthors
                kMDItemRecipients
                kMDItemCoverage
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
            </displayattrs>
        </type>
        <type name="com.microsoft.outlook15.note">
            <allattrs>kMDItemTitle
                com_microsoft_outlook_recordID
                kMDItemContentCreationDate
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_text_content
                kMDItemTextContent
                kMDItemKeywords
                kMDItemProjects
                com_microsoft_outlook_folderID
                com_microsoft_outlook_accountID
                com_microsoft_outlook_projects
                com_microsoft_outlook_categories
                com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory
            </allattrs>
            <displayattrs>kMDItemTitle
                kMDItemContentCreationDate
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
            </displayattrs>
        </type>
        <type name="com.microsoft.outlook15.task">
            <allattrs>com_microsoft_outlook_has_text_content
                kMDItemTextContent
                kMDItemTitle
                com_microsoft_outlook_recordID
                kMDItemContentModificationDate
                kMDItemComment
                com_microsoft_outlook_recurring
                com_microsoft_outlook_recurrence
                com_microsoft_outlook_recurrence_type
                com_microsoft_outlook_priority
                com_microsoft_outlook_folderID
                com_microsoft_outlook_accountID
                kMDItemProjects
                com_microsoft_outlook_projects
                com_microsoft_outlook_categories
                com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasStartDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_startDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_hasDueDate
                kMDItemDueDate
                com_microsoft_outlook_has_reminder
                com_microsoft_outlook_completed
                com_microsoft_outlook_completedDate
            </allattrs>
            <displayattrs>kMDItemTitle
                kMDItemDueDate
            </displayattrs>
        </type>
    </types>
</schema>
```

Hope that helps.

Another related link: http://blog.stevex.net/2011/03/outlook-2011-smart-folder-with-raw-query/
Info on `mdl` query syntax: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html

Value examples that you can make a raw query against.

```
com_microsoft_outlook_accountID                = 1
com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses   = (
    "*** Email address is removed for privacy ***"
)
com_microsoft_outlook_categories               = (
    98
)
com_microsoft_outlook_completed                = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_flagged                  = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_folderID                 = 108
com_microsoft_outlook_forwarded                = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_has_attachments          = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_has_mentioned_me         = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_has_reminder             = 1
com_microsoft_outlook_has_text_content         = 1
com_microsoft_outlook_hasDueDate               = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_hasStartDate             = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_messageReceived          = 2016-09-01 20:46:56 +0000
com_microsoft_outlook_messageSent              = 2016-09-01 20:46:54 +0000
com_microsoft_outlook_primaryCategory          = 98
com_microsoft_outlook_priority                 = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_recordID                 = 646385
com_microsoft_outlook_recpient_email_addresses = (
    "*** Email address is removed for privacy ***"
)
com_microsoft_outlook_redirected               = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_repliedTo                = 0
com_microsoft_outlook_size                     = 4
com_microsoft_outlook_toEmailAddresses         = (
    "*** Email address is removed for privacy ***"
)
com_microsoft_outlook_toRecipients             = (
    "GUPTA, Sunil"
)
com_microsoft_outlook_unread                   = 1
kMDItemAlternateNames                          = (
    "/Users/i804008/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages/143/8F74F504-DF2B-40C7-8AFE-7AF73D95486D.olk15Message"
)
kMDItemAuthors                               = (
    "Wu, Will"
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate                     = 2016-09-01 20:46:56 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate                 = 2016-09-01 20:47:02 +0000
kMDItemContentType                             = "com.microsoft.outlook15.message"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                         = (
    "com.microsoft.outlook15.message",
    "public.email-message",
    "public.message",
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                               = 2016-09-01 20:47:01 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                             = "aabbccdd"
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate                     = 2016-09-01 20:47:02 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate                          = 2016-09-01 20:47:01 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode                           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags                           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon                         = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden                     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery                          = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                               = 0
kMDItemFSName                               = "8F74F504-DF2B-40C7-8AFE-7AF73D95486D.olk15Message"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                             = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID                          = 1694527156
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID                           = 718023034
kMDItemFSSize                               = 4583
kMDItemFSTypeCode                              = ""
kMDItemKind                               = "olk15_message"
kMDItemLastUsedDate                            = 2016-09-01 20:46:56 +0000
kMDItemLogicalSize                             = 4583
kMDItemPhysicalSize                            = 8192
kMDItemRecipients                              = (
    "GUPTA, Sunil"
)
kMDItemTitle                               = "aabbccdd"
kMDItemUseCount                               = 1
kMDItemUsedDates                               = (
    "2016-09-01 04:00:00 +0000"
kMDItemOwnerUserID                    = 718023034
com_microsoft_outlook_accountID        = 1
com_microsoft_outlook_allDay           = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, @phyatt!  This worked perfectly for me in Outlook for Mac 2019 on 10.12.  My sent emails finally show up as part of the conversation in the message list, and clicking on a sent email from the conversation view in the reading pane no longer opens it in a new window.

Comment: Great answer, steps are very easy to follow! While this gets the conversation threads the way I like them, but it also includes emails that are simply sent list (i.e. not ones that are part of a conversation) which is because this process simply merges both the Inbox and Sent. For some this may not work out for them depending on the volume of emails sent, but I'll probably continue on with this combined folder. Thanks!

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a workaround. Following this approach, I'm not able to see replies in conversation in my inbox, but rather I have to make a Smart Folder for any folder/sub-folder I have and move there when I need to. The workaround is a good idea, but not practical if you have many sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes a little bit too late, but I found a quick and dirty workaround, which doesn't really interfere too much with a normal workflow.

**Just add yourself as a recipient of your own emails.**

Simple as that. You will see your own answers in the conversation mode thread, since you will *actually receive* these emails. Your name will show as the sender so it's easy to see these are actually *sent* replies.

Not ideal, but it works and it's a non-intrusive workaround while we wait for Microsoft to fix what I can only describe as an annoying bug

Comment: The same recommendation is given in the accepted answer: "BCC yourself automatically"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my PC when I upgraded Outlook.  I was able to resolve it by going to File/Account Settings and then changing by default email account, rebooting and then changing it back and rebooting.  All works fine in both Inboxes!

Comment: This question is for the macOS version of Outlook, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed on Outlook 16.53

Answer (score 0):

Try [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) which manage threads the right way since many years ( probably more than 10 )

```
View > Sort by > Threaded
```

As a collateral benefit Thunderbird is an open source software thus you can trust it because you can check. I used it at a large scale company ( ~ 3000 users ). Compared with Outlook, Mail, Thunderbird was the one with the less support questions and the less malware attacks ( on a more than 10 years security supervising ). On the other hand the loser was… ; I let you guess it as an easy game .

The future of Thunderbird is unsure, but I am still using it to provide me a common and efficient interface to many web mail servers which are much too slow to work with ( Gmail… ).

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected when the "New Outlook" experience for Mac is enabled.
I did a comparison between the "Old" and the "New" Outlook and indeed the main message list behaviour is different between the two.

The version I am running:

```
Microsoft Outlook for Mac
Version 16.71 (230312000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

File: Options: Mail - check "Enable preview for Rights protected emails"

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Go to accounts settings and check the box Use Cached Exchange Mode, close outlook and reopen

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: @ben What other ramifications will this have?